# Decrypt encrypted disk to make second partition

Tags: partitioning, encryption, gparted

I have a problem. When I install Ubuntu, I make only one partition and encrypt this partition. Now I want to make second partition with different file type. How I can "decrypt" partition or... take 100GB from existing 500GB partiotion.

P.S. I already tried from "boot cd" but gparded have problem with encrypted partition.

How I can:

a) Make second partition from "live system".

b) Take encryption off, so gparted from "live cd" can do the work??

Comment: There is no way to do this. Backup your data, music, photos, and videos. Reformat your hard drive and start from the beginning.

Comment: There is no other way, to resize encrypted disk other than format hard drive? :(

Comment: I will be happy if someone tells me, I am wrong. But, as far as I know, it can't be done.

Comment: There are ways to enlarge a partition, but shrinking I'm not so sure, should be possible for ext filesystems... You might be able to use a live dvd/usb and "decrypt" the encrypted drive/partition (`cryptsetup luksOpen`), then [shrink the ext3 filesystem](https://www.howtoforge.com/linux_resizing_ext3_partitions) (probably removing the journal & using resize2fs), but then you'd have to shrink the LUKS "container", and I don't know how to do that...

Comment: @Xen2050: too complex and error-prone...  See answer below.

Comment: I don't had time, so... I made backup and restore :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Great security comes with great responsibility"...  ;-)

The conclusion of @user68186 is correct: backup everything and recreate.  I would back up everything twice: one system back-up using [CloneZilla](http://clonezilla.org) `disk-to-image` (will be encrypted as well) and one file backup (please do that one **unencrypted** to avoid more trouble later on, use your current back-up program.) of the following directories:

```
bin        Videos     Desktop    Pictures                 
Documents  Music      Public     Downloads  Templates
```

Read this [Q&A](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) on the strategy to use.  You’re definitely user type 4!